# Adding section to appendix causes a compile error

Tags: sectioning, numbering, appendices

### Background

Include multiple appendixes in a book. (Using KOMA Script v2.)

### Problem

I have isolated the problem and created a minimal example to demonstrate the issue:

- [Preamble](http://www.mediafire.com/?y31wmta95xn6al3)
- [Working LyX File](http://www.mediafire.com/?9rmgxnu1ny2g7tf)
- [Broken LyX File](http://www.mediafire.com/?zsvv85cl8l0vvid)

The *only* difference (according to gVim's `diff` tool) between `good.lyx` and `bad.lyx` are the following lines:

```
\begin_layout Subsection
jasper.php
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
TODO
\end_layout
```

Loading `good.lyx` into LyX works as expected: a PDF can be created. Loading `bad.lyx` into LyX does not work as expected. The following error results:

> Missing number, treated as zero.
>
> \end{document}
>
> A number should have been here; I inserted '0'.
>   (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
>   look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

### Questions

- Why does typing one more subsection cause an error?
- How can the error be resolved so that any number of sections and subsections can be added to the appendix?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't like files being stored externally on file hosting services which open browser windows with promotionial content when I try to open your files to debug.

Comment: @Stefan: Sorry about that; it was the first free file sharing host I found.

Comment: not a big problem :-) there may be free and opensource pastebin services too. But the best is always to reduce to a handy example. ;-) LyX files are also just in text format and could be posted.

Comment: @Stefan: Will find a pastebin for next time; I just cannot bear to paste huge code snippets. (Now if there was a way to "fold" or close the snippet, that would be altogether different.)

Comment: I would like to see a code folding feature, unfortunately it has been declined: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5199/please-add-the-ability-to-fold-blocks-of-code-in-questions-and-answers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What does this harmless subsection command? It starts a new page! And this page has a different page style. The first page has page style plain because it's the beginning of a chapter, but the next page has scrheadings style. There we may search the problem.

It is in your preamble:

```
\rehead{\textsc{\ChapterTitle \ChapterNumberIfNeededEven}}
\lohead{\textsc{\ChapterNumberIfNeededOdd \ChapterTitle}}
...
\def\ChapterNumberIfNeededEven{%
  \ifnum 0<\thechapter{} $ \star $ \chaptername{} \thechapter{} \fi
}
\def\ChapterNumberIfNeededOdd{%
  \ifnum 0<\thechapter{} \chaptername{} \thechapter{} $ \star $ \fi
}
```

Don't compare a number 0 with `\thechapter` - in your appendix `\thechapter` is "A" ! Instead, something like

```
 \ifnum\value{chapter}=0 ...
```

could work.

On a plain chapter starting page that error could not occur.